# Ubuntu doesn't boot after failed update from 20.04 lts to 20.10

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, upgrade, 20.04

I was trying to upgrade ubuntu version from 20.04 lts to its newest version 20.10 . I was watching the upgrading process but left it for 10 mintutes or so..when I came back it showed me the login screen . I entered my password and pressed ENTER but it didn't start and was completely blank for 5 minutes so I shut it off.

Now When I boot my computer I can see the GRUB menu as usual.
[image]

I tried to enter ubuntu but it doesn't work just blank .

So I tried opening the terminal using Ctl+Alt+T and F-keys as well. When I try to boot it in recovery mode it the same thing happens. I don't get the normal option menu that comes in recovery mode.

**NOTE: I am booting in insecure mode .**

I tried it all..can anybody please help me out with this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps an Ubuntu and GRUB reinstallation would fix your issue. Download them onto an SD or USB like normal, and reinstall the tools, making sure to save any data or settings you would like to keep.

If this doesn't work, or you have perhaps already tried this, as a last resort only, delete the partitions Ubuntu is on and reinstall from scratch. If you absolutely must delete Ubuntu, be sure to back up your partitions to another external hard drive or separate storage partition on the disk like Local Disk C:\ (or whatever you have Windows assigned to.) I repeat, this is a last resort only. Be sure to keep what you want.

Comment: Isn't there anything else I can do? Since none of it works I'll have to reinstall it

Comment: @kirtipurohit If Ubuntu isn't booting, unfortunately no. But you can reinstall without data loss if you need to.

Answer (score 1):

When in the GRUB menu, if you scroll down to advanced options and choose an older version of GNU to boot with, your computer should boot up properly, allowing you to more easily back up data and potentially fix issues.

Comment: Yes . I backed up my data via advanced options but I had to re-install and setup everything because the boot file got corrupted

Answer (score 0):

i had the exact same issue as well.
i had to create a new partition and i was able to mount the failed partition from the new one i created.

1. create a new partition
   first i downloaded the ubuntu OS (i did 20.04) to a USB drive and using a windows machine i made it bootable with Rufus(https://rufus.ie/en/)
   here is a link to guide you :https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows#1-overview or you can use https://itsfoss.com/install-ubuntu
2. accessing the files
   in ubuntu 20.04 go to the files program and on the left hand side you should see the "+ other locations" option (it may be at the bottom left)
   once you click it you should see all the partitions of your hard disk.
   then you need to click the one with your data then it will take you to the root or base of your drive.
   then go to home then you can see the users then you keep going until you can see and copy your data.

Comment: This has nothing to do with the question.